# Edit multiple objects in array using mongoose (MongoDB)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

So I tried several ways, but I can't, I can modify several objects with the same key but I can't modify any with different keys, if anyone can help me is quite a complex problem

```js
{ 
  id: 123, 
  "infos": [ 
    { name: 'Joe', value: 'Disabled', id: 0 }, 
    { name: 'Adam', value: 'Enabled', id: 0 }
  ]
};
```

In my database I have a collection with an array and several objects inside which gives this.

I want to modify these objects, filter by their name and modify the value.

To give you a better example, my site returns me an object with the new data, and I want to modify the database object with the new object, without clearing the array, the name key never changes.

```js
const object = [
  { name: 'Joe', value: 'Hey', id: 1 }, 
  { name: 'Adam', value: 'None', id: 1 }
];

for(const obj in object) {
  Schema.findOneAndUpdate({ id: 123 }, {
    $set: {
      [`infos.${obj}.value`]: "Test"
    }
  })
}
```

This code works but it is not optimized, it makes several requests, I would like to do everything in one request, and also it doesn't update the id, only the value.

If anyone can help me that would be great, I've looked everywhere and can't find anything

**My schema structure**

```js
new Schema({
  id: { "type": String, "required": true, "unique": true }, 
  infos: []
})
```

I use the `$addToSet` method to insert objects into the `infos` array

Comment: Please add your schema structure.

Comment: I edited with the schema

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try This :

```
db.collection.update({
  id: 123,
  
},
{
  $set: {
    "infos.$[x].value": "Value",
    "infos.$[x].name": "User"
  }
},
{
  arrayFilters: [
    {
      "x.id": {
        $in: [ 
          1 
        ]
      }
    },
    
  ],
  multi: true
})
```

1. The all positional `$[]` operator acts as a placeholder for all elements in the array field.
2. In `$in` you can use dynamic `array` of id.
   Ex :

   const ids = [1,2,..n]

   db.collection.update(
   `//Same code as it is...`
   {
   arrayFilters: [
   {
   "x.id": {
   $in: ids
   }
   },
   ],
   multi: true
   })

MongoPlayGround Link : https://mongoplayground.net/p/Tuz831lkPqk

Comment: But i have an array with 30k users and i only want to edit 10-15 of them not all, i also want to edit multiples values in the object

Comment: In this code I have seen two object users with the same id 1. In that case I would assume that there are multiple user objects with the same id. and in my code, I have talked about how to change the field of multiple by using multiple id.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you look for something like this:

```
db.collection.update({},
{
  $set: {
   "infos.$[x].value": "test1",
   "infos.$[x].id": 10,
   "infos.$[y].value": "test2",
   "infos.$[y].id": 20
   }
 },
{
 arrayFilters: [
{
  "x.name": "Adam"
},
{
  "y.name": "Joe"
}
],
  multi: true
})
```

Explained:

You define arrayFilters for all names in objects you have and update the values & id in all documents ...

[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/gMG01xUn20q)

Comment: Yes it's that, but if i got 10 users, how can i automate this, i don't want to add 10 filters

Comment: How can i add an array to the $set method ? I dont want to add each line manually

Comment: Btw , you can prepare array of  many update operations in single bulkWrite call , check here if you want to reduce the many single calls to the database: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/?_ga=2.210433810.669799643.1647334453-1341466864.1641598014